# PostgreSQL how to find row IDs based on aggregated metrics

Tags: sql, postgresql, math

I have a table in a PostgreSQL database that looks more or less like this:

| ID | Side | Amount | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BUY | 8 | 107295.000000000 |
| 2 | SELL | 18 | 107300.000000000 |
| 3 | SELL | 21 | 107305.000000000 |
| 4 | BUY | 17 | 107310.000000000 |

And I have some aggregated metrics that look like this:
`{'BUY': {'amount_sum': 6655, 'price_avg': 105961.497370398197}, 'SELL': {'amount_sum': 6655, 'price_avg': 106214.787377911345}}`

And I need to find the row IDs that match these metrics. How would I go about doing this?

I've read a bit into PostgreSQL documentation and I've tried using GROUP BY on SIDE, then using the HAVING clause, but wasn't successful.

===================================================

To clarify, given this table and input:

| ID | Side | Amount | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BUY | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | SELL | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | SELL | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | BUY | 1 | 3 |
| 5 | SELL | 8 | 1 |
| 6 | BUY | 5 | 2 |

`{'BUY': {'amount_sum': 3, 'price_avg': 2}, 'SELL': {'amount_sum': 10, 'price_avg': 1}}`

I would the expected output to be:
`BUY: ids[1,4] SELL: ids[3,5]` that's because for ids 1 and 4, which have side as BUY, the sum of the amount column is 3, and the average of the price column is 2. And for ids 3 and 5, which have side as SELL, the sum of the amount column is 10, and the average of the price column is 1.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are asking.  Can you provide sample data and expected output?

Comment: Strings/json are not tables. You can't have a random value somewhere in the db like `{'BUY': {'amount_sum': 3, 'price_avg': 2}, 'SELL': {'amount_sum': 10, 'price_avg': 1}}`

Comment: They're not random. That's a generic input. What I mean is the query should be something like `SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE SIDE = 'BUY' HAVING SUM(AMOUNT) = 3 AND AVG(PRICE) = 2`

Comment: You are basicly looking for combinations that would aggregate to specific values.  This is not possible in SQL.  Also seems there is a fair chance of multiple solutions to any given aggregate values.

Comment: Multiple solutions are unlikely given that the actual queries should find thousands of IDs, with a very specific combination of amount and price aggregations. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

@Gabriel Tkacz, I have not 50 reputaton to comment) and ask my question as "answer".
From input table was [expected](https://dbfiddle.uk/UMuZ-0Rk):

```
{'BUY':{ 'Ids':[1,4,6]','amount_sum':8','price_avg':2}
{'SELL':{ 'Ids':[2,3,5]','amount_sum':11','price_avg':1.3333333333333333}
```

why excluded [6] on BUY side and [2] on SELL side in your explanation
BUY: ids[1,4] SELL: ids[3,5]